# WCF - BasicHttpBinding, No user name and/or password is available, name: null, password: null

Tags: vb.net, wcf, web-services

I'm trying to use a third party web service which is secured with a user/pass. I believe I have done what is needed to authenticate and set the user and pass, but it seems to not be including them in the http header or something...

When attempting to call;

```
nameList.AddRange(service.getBlobNameByIdAndSectionId(section, id))
```

I get this error;

```
No user name and/or password is available, name: null, password: null
```

Full code:

```
Private Function GetVendorService() As Services.ServiceClient
    Dim binding As New BasicHttpBinding(BasicHttpSecurityMode.Transport)

    binding.Security.Message.ClientCredentialType = BasicHttpMessageCredentialType.UserName
    binding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.Basic
    Dim ea As New EndpointAddress(GetVendorServiceURL())

    Dim service As New Services.ServiceClient(binding, ea)
    service.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "user"
    service.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = "password"

    Return service

End Function

Public Function GetVendorServiceURL() As String
    Select Case Informix.HostType
        Case HostServerType.Stage
            Return "https://url-s.net:8443/cxf/Service/v1/ws"
        Case HostServerType.Dev
            Return "https://url-d.net:8443/cxf/Service/v1/ws"
        Case Else 'Live
            Return "https://url.net:8443/cxf/Service/v1/ws"
    End Select
End Function

Private Function GetPdfListById(ByVal Id As Integer, ByVal Section As SectionId) As List(Of Services.blobName)
    Dim service As Services.ServiceClient = GetVendorService()
    Dim nameList As New List(Of Services.blobName)
    service.Open()
    nameList.AddRange(service.getBlobNameByIdAndSectionId(section, id))
    service.Close()
    Return nameList
End Function
```

app.config

```
<system.serviceModel>
<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="ServiceSoapBinding" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
      openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
      allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
      maxBufferSize="65536" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536"
      messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered"
      useDefaultWebProxy="true">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
        maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
      <security mode="Transport">
        <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None"
          realm="" />
        <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
      </security>
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<client>
  <endpoint address="https://url.net:8443/cxf/Service/v1/ws"
    binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="ServiceSoapBinding"
    contract="Services.Service"
    name="ServiceSoapPort" />
</client>
```

Comment: Well, in order to eliminate some potential confusion, your second binding definition (`ServiceSoapBinding1`) is not currently referenced (in the code you have shown), so will be ignored and you could safely remove it.

Comment: Thanks, missed that when posting. Removed it from the example.

Comment: Stupid question, but do you have any documentation about how to do this? What does the third party say?

Comment: @hugh - Only documentation found online for sending security for Basic Authentication in WCF, I have personally never used WCF before this. When seeing we were having issues the third party sent us links to msdn code.....  They use Basic Authentication and are using ServiceMix, which is the extent of my knowledge about their end. I am using BasicHttpBinding because they use Soap1.1 instead of 1.2, so WsHttpBinding doesn't like that, using a custom binding created in code to use Soap1.1 gives a MustUnderstandHeaders error, and I'm not sure if that's a step forward or backward.

Comment: Additionally, using `BasicHttpSecurityMode.TransportWithMessageCredential` will give me a MustUnderstand headers error.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After a lot of issues, I found that for some reason the Authorization header was not being sent to the service. In order to include it I had to do the below for the call to the service. What I am still confused about is why this is an issue. From what I thought BasicHttpBinding was supposed to include the credentials in the header by default? Any insight by someone as to why this was an issue for me would be greatly appreciated. And a good answer to that may still get the +50.

```
Private Function GetPdfListById(ByVal Id As Integer, ByVal Section As SectionId) As List(Of VendorGuideService.vogBlobName)
    Using service As Service.ServiceClient = GetVendorService()
        Dim nameList As New List(Of Service.blobName)
        Using scope As ServiceModel.OperationContextScope = New ServiceModel.OperationContextScope(service.InnerChannel)
            Dim request As New ServiceModel.Channels.HttpRequestMessageProperty()
            request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic " & Convert.ToBase64String(System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(service.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName & ":" & _
                                                                                                    service.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password)))
            ServiceModel.OperationContext.Current.OutgoingMessageProperties(ServiceModel.Channels.HttpRequestMessageProperty.Name) = request
            nameList.AddRange(service.getBlobNameByIdAndSectionId(section, id))
        End Using
        Return nameList
    End Using
End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

If the authentication required is HTTP Basic only, then you need to specify the basicHttpBinding's security as follows:

```
<basicHttpBinding>
    <binding ...>
        <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
            <transport clientCredentialType="Basic" />
        </security>
    </binding>
</basicHttpBinding>
```

You can of course choose to specify these in code instead.

The actual credentials must always be given in code:

```
client.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "userName";
client.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = "password";
```

Comment: The service is using Basic, but if I use transportCredentialOnly it doesn't like the https url. Also, if I do what I am doing in the code does that app.config binding even used for anything?